# Can the Broom of Flying move underwater?

Tags: dnd-5e, flight, underwater

More specifically: can I order the Broom of Flying to dive into the sea so a sinking PC (several meters underwater) can grab it, then order it to fly out and back to me, saving the PC? I figured, creatures with literal wings of course couldn't move through water that easily, but a magically propelled broom wouldn't be aware of the substance it is surrounded with, would it?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### Flying movement is intended for use in the air

Flying Movement is described on p 196 PHB

> Flying creatures enjoy many benefits of mobility, but they must also **deal with the danger of falling**. If a flying creature is knocked prone, has its speed reduced to 0, or is otherwise deprived of the ability to move, the creature falls, unless it has the ability to hover or it is being held aloft by magic, such as by the fly spell.

Underwater, there is no danger of falling. When you are moving under water and stop moving, you at worst sink slowly. So like in common language usage, you can use a flying speed to move through air. To move through water, you need a swim speed, or you need to pay double movement, which normally refers to your walking speed. It would be up to your DM to allow using the flying speed of the broom to swim like that spending 2 feet of movement for each foot traveled.

We can also look at example monsters. For example, the **Young Bronze Dragon** has a fly speed of 80 ft. and a Swim speed of 40 ft. If it could use its fly speed to swim, it would not need a swim speed.

Of course, for the sake of dramatic action, you as DM can always allow such dive-bombing. You are given explicit license for this by the game (DMG p. 4):

> The D&D rules help you and the other players have
> a good time, but the rules aren't in charge. You're the DM, and you are in charge of the game.

Comment: Having a swim speed also means you can make melee attacks without disadvantage (https://www.5esrd.com/gamemastering/underwater-combat/).  So even if you allow fly speed to work as your speed for the normal rule of movement costing an extra foot per foot underwater without a swim speed, Fly 80 / Swim 40 still matters for things other than movement.  (And for simplicity to avoid DMs having to figure out how fly speeds interact with water.)  But I'd guess the intent is that you can use your walk speed when swimming, since that usually just gets called your "speed".

Comment: @PeterCordes I agree with everything in your comment. I thought about bringing both these up, and  it got bit long-winded for a secondary point when the main argument is based on the description of the flying speed.